# Magento 2.1.5: Mysql Error when browse Category page which have no products

Tags: database, category-products, magento2.1.5

When i browse to one category page that do not have any product i receive a report error.

The report says:

> a:4:{i:0;s:2291:"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END, CASE e.entity_id END, `cat_index_position` ASC, `cat_index`.`position` ASC,' at line 5, query was: SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`updated_at`, `e`.`sku`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`width`, `e`.`count_products`, `e`.`swatch_image`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable` FROM `mgyg_catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`
>    INNER JOIN `mgyg_catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='357'
>    INNER JOIN `mgyg_catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
>    LEFT JOIN `mgyg_cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1
>    INNER JOIN `mgyg_search_tmp_58c98af0dd8588_51220712` AS `search_result` ON e.entity_id = search_result.entity_id WHERE (e.entity_id IN(NULL)) AND (e.entity_id IN(NULL)) AND (e.entity_id IN(NULL)) ORDER BY CASE e.entity_id END, CASE e.entity_id END, `cat_index_position` ASC, `cat_index`.`position` ASC, CASE e.entity_id END
>    LIMIT 39";i:1;s:6726:"

How can i resolve this error?